# Why is "more" of ISeq not named "rest"?

Tags: clojure

```
public interface ISeq extends IPersistentCollection {
  Object first();
  ISeq next();
  ISeq more();
  ISeq cons(Object o);
}
```

`more` method of `ISeq` interface seems to be functioning just `rest`. Why is it named `more` not `rest`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information is my interpretation of doing some archeology on the Clojure git repository.

Originally there was only `rest`, which returned `nil` instead of the emtpy list as it does today. When Rich introduced [lazyness](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/b8e333fb3437dca760f16136ed074a4dd463fe35#L19L23), it was then renamed `next`, and `ISeq` gained the `more` method. `ASeq` implements the `more` method to return an empty seq instead of `nil`, and leaves the `next` methond abstract.  At some point after this the `rest` function was brought back to life as the non-seq, empty list-returning version we know today, but the Java code wasn't refactored.